# Deserialize arbitrary JSON object with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, json.net

I want to deserialize a JSON strin like this

```
{
   "status":"1",
   "since":"1245626956',
   "list":{
      "1":{
         "item_id":"1"
      },
      "2":{
         "item_id":"2"
      }
   }
}
```

For this I have an object that parses that

```
public class ListResponse
{
    public String status { get; set; }
    public String since { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<String, Item> list { get; set; }
}
```

I use this sentence:

```
ListResponse list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListResponse>(message);
```

That works well but I have a problem because response can be something like this

```
{
   "status":"1",
   "since":"1245626956',
   "list":[]
}
```

When trying to deserialize that an exception raises because needs an array to parse 'list' but my object has a IDictionary.

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,Item]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
```

How can I handle this issue without using Linq to obtain JObject and do the mapping "by hand"?

Comment: Why are you getting varying values for `list`?  It ought to consistently be either a dictionary or an array, right?

Comment: It has to be consistent but when list is not empty is a dictionary and when is empty is an array. If I modify the string while debugging, changing `"list":[]` for `"list":{}` there is no error.

Comment: Shouldn't the source of your JSON data be giving you `{}` when it's empty instead of `[]`?  Is there any way you can fix this?

Comment: What happens if you add the `[JsonArray]` attribute to the `list` declaration as the error message suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround would be to do this before deserializing:

```
yourString = yourString.Replace("\"list\":[]", "\"list\":{}");
```

Comment: This is the first thing I thought but it is a patch I don't like too much. I can't do anything with the source because I'm consuming services from a public API.